# Inter-rater analysis of complex dataset

Tags: r, dataframe

My dataset is ethogram responses. I had 5 raters score the same 53 videos each. These 53 videos contain 28 different dogs. I now have a dataset consisting of 55 columns and 265 rows. The first three columns are to identify which rater has scored that ethogram and which video that ethogram is from. I have divided my ordinal and categorical data into their own subsets.

```
# Melt the data----                              
# Convert all non-identifier columns to character type

ordinal <- ordinal %>%
  mutate(across(-c(Code, Data.Collection.Number, Assessor), as.character))

ordinal_melted_data <- ordinal %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(Code, Data.Collection.Number, Assessor),
               names_to = "variable",
               values_to = "value") 

##Categorical 
# Convert all non-identifier columns to character type

categorical <- categorical %>%
  mutate(across(-c(Code, Data.Collection.Number, Assessor), as.character))

# Melt the data
categorical_melted_data <- categorical %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(Code, Data.Collection.Number, Assessor),
               names_to = "variable",
               values_to = "value")
```

Using my melted data I attempted to use Fleisskappa and ICC. Fleisskappa on my categorical data is giving me the incorrect number of raters and subjects, i should have 5 raters, 53 subjects. Instead I am getting 3 raters and 28 subjects.

```
# Get unique variable names from categorical_melted_data
variable_names <- unique(categorical_melted_data$variable)

# Initialize a list to store results
results <- list()

# Iterate over each variable
for (variable in variable_names) {
  # Subset data for the current variable
  variable_data <- categorical_melted_data[categorical_melted_data$variable == variable, ]
  
  # Print unique raters and subjects
  cat("Variable:", variable, "\n")
  cat("Unique raters:", unique(variable_data$Assessor), "\n")
  cat("Unique subjects:", unique(variable_data$Code), "\n")
  
  # Create the contingency table
  contingency_table <- table(variable_data$Code, variable_data$value)
  
  # Calculate Fleiss' Kappa
  fleisskappa_result <- kappam.fleiss(contingency_table)
  
  # Store the results
  results[[variable]] <- fleisskappa_result$value
}

# Print results along with raters and subjects details
for (variable in variable_names) {
  cat("Variable:", variable, "\n")
  
  # Display details on raters and subjects
  cat("Number of raters:", ncol(contingency_table), "\n")
  cat("Number of subjects:", nrow(contingency_table), "\n")
  
  # Display Fleiss' Kappa value for the variable
  cat("Fleiss' Kappa:", results[[variable]], "\n\n")
}
```

And just to clarify, my melted data format is 5 columns (Video Code, Assessor, Data Collection Number, variable, value)

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: @geek45, I've just added some sample data to the description. Hope that helps.

Comment: No, it does not help, since images for data should generally be avoided. Use e.g. `dput()` for including a suitable example data set. Also you should shorten your question and clarify the problem within a shorter text. Currently it is full of not needed passages which make it hard to follow.

Comment: @JenniferKenny What is your approach to conducting the inter-rater "analysis"? Can you add details, package, code?

Comment: @Ben I've changed the description of my data and added some more code.